# Solving $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n\log(n)$ without master theorem

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation

Solving $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2}) + n\log(n)$ without master theorem, given $T(1) = 1$

My approach with recurrence tree:

$n \sim n\log(n)$

$\frac{n}{2} \sim 2 \frac{n}{2}\log(\frac{n}{2})$

$\frac{n}{4} \sim 4 \frac{n}{4}\log(\frac{n}{4})$

Hence the summation must follow as:

$$T(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)} n\log(\frac{n}{2^i})$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)} n(\log(n) - i)$$
$$=(n\log(n) \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)}i) - (\sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)} i)$$

I can not go further from here, any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For direct result let's use direct summation assuming $n=2^k$:
$$T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + n\log(n)=2\left[ 2T\left(\frac{n}{2^2}\right) +\frac{n}{2}\log \frac{n}{2}\right]+ n\log(n) = \\
=2^2T\left(\frac{n}{2^2}\right)+n\log \frac{n}{2}+ n\log(n) =\\
=\cdots=\\
=2^kT\left(1\right)+n\log \frac{n}{2^{k-1}}+ \cdots +n\log \frac{n}{2}+n\log(n)=\\
=2^kT\left(1\right) +n\log 2 + \cdots +n\log 2^k=\\
=nT\left(1\right) +n\log 2 (1 + \cdots + k) =nT\left(1\right) + \frac{k(k+1)}{2} n\log 2 \in \Theta (n \log^2 n)$$
where, of course, $k=\log_2 n$. Hope you can obtain from here everything what you wanted.

At end let me note also, that $n \sim n\log(n)$ and other equivalences, which you are using, are not correct, if we understand standard $\lim \frac{f}{g}=1$, for symbol "$\sim$". Correct is, for example, $n = o(n\log(n))$ etc.

Comment: Also thanks for your hint.

Answer (score 1):

From your recursion, beacuse of $T(n)$ have a term $n\log n$ we can conclude that :
$$T(n)=\Omega(n\log n)$$
and from your summation :

$$T(n)=n\log(n) \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)}i - \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)} i<n\log(n) \sum_{i=0}^{\log(n)}i\simeq n\log^2 n$$
Finally
$$n\log n\leq T(n)\leq n\log^2 n$$
Next step, we try to improve lower bound by induction:
Suppose $T(n)\geq c\times n\log^2 n$
$$\rightarrow 2\times c\times\frac{n}{2}\times \log^2 \frac{n}{2}+ n\log n\geq c\times n\log^2 n$$
$$=c\times n\times \log n\times(\log n+\frac{1}{c})\geq c\times n\times \log n\times(\log n+\frac{1}{\log n})\hspace{20pt}\text{if $c\leq$ 1 }\square$$
For sufficiently large $n$ (i.e. $n\to \infty$), and base case  above inequality is correct. So we conclude that  as $n\to \infty$
$$T(n)=\theta (n\log^2 n)$$